# How do I change the "from email address" associated with PHP contact form

Tags: php

Everything with my PHP code is working properly, the only thing is, is that when I received an email from the contact form, the "from" for my website is @p3plcpnl0547.prod.phx3.secureserver.net.

Example Image of email from contact form

[image]

How can I change the @p3plcpnl0547.prod.phx3.secureserver.net?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['send_email'])) {

    //collect the form values
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    // set the email properties

    $to = 'alicia.angner@yahoo.com';
    $subject = "Contact Form Submission";
    $from =  $email ;
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers = "From: $from";
    $headers = "$name \n $phone \n $email";

    //attempt to send the mail, catch errors if they occur
    try {
        mail($to,$subject,$headers,$message);
        $msg = "<strong>Your mail was sent successfully!</strong>";
    }catch(Exception $e) {
        $msg = "An Exception was thrown: ".$e -> getMessage()."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your headers variable is just overwriting itself over and over instead of concatenating. You want to do `$headers .= "...";` (notice the `.` before the `=`).

Comment: That and you CAN'T have your server masquerade as some other mail server. e.g. if you do `From: example@gmail.com`, it'll probably get trashed as spam since your server isn't an authorized google mail source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting the $headers variable on each line, you instead want to append to it. Replace:

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers = "From: $from";
$headers = "$name \n $phone \n $email";
```

With:

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $from";
$headers .= "$name \n $phone \n $email";
```

I'm not too sure what that last line is accomplishing, should it be in the $message instead?

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. I'm exactly sure what you mean by the "last line". I'm still learning PHP.

Comment: Keep going, you're doing well! I was puzzled by this as it's not a valid header: `$headers .= "$name \n $phone \n $email";` Headers should be in the format `Header-Name: value`

Comment: okay. $headers is what I've learned thus far. Are you saying I should use Header-Name instead? "$name \n $phone \n $email"; is still being sent in the "message" just not within $message, should I change this?

Comment: What you have is correct up until that line. The name, phone and email are only present in headers, not message. I've just seen that you are sending through $headers in the part of mail() reserved for the message, which explains why you see it! Double check https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php and change `mail($to,$subject,$headers,$message);` in your code to `mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);`

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit the `sendmail_from` specified in `php.ini` to set a defaut from parameter. 
source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php.

Comment: I'm not using php.ini. How would I go about this?

Comment: php.ini is the PHP configuration file, you may or may not have access to this file depending on your hosting configuration. If you can't access your server through a shell, you likely can't. You should set the headers like in the above answer, that was your main problem was that you weren't concatenating the headers with the .= operator.

Comment: I concatenated the headers with .=, but now it's not working. I'm not even getting an email.

Answer (score 0):

While your immediate problem has been pointed out by other answers, noting that you're overwriting the value of the variable `$headers`, resulting in your headers not being set properly, there is also additional information you need to consider when sending emails from PHP this way.

PHP's `mail()` function typically just talks to your [sendmail binary](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/download/) (*on *nix systems*), which could be an actual MTA or it could just be some script that talks to an email server like [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/), for example.

The reason this is important is because an email can have both a `Sender` header as well as a `From` header, and they can be different. Typically the MTA is responsible for setting the `Sender` header, which if you care about setting this information properly in the email header is important.

You can typically change the sender in your sendmail config from `/etc/mail/access` or `/etc/sendmail/access` where you can specify which users are allowed to send from which email addresses. These rules may vary depending on which MTA you're relying on and emails from unauthorized senders may be rejected by your MTA or even the recepient as this could trigger warning headers in the email. So be sure to take that under consideration.

## Future Considerations for Email

For learning purposes this is fine, but if you intend to deal with email in production I always advise against using `mail()` in PHP setting up, configuring, and maintaining your own email server can be a rather arduous process.

Instead consider relying on an email service like [AWS' SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) or [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/). They're more reliable, less likely to have your emails wind up in spam folders, and a lot less likely to get your IP addresses on blacklists for spam. They also have well documented APIs and are more suitable for sending out bulk emails without typing up your own server or PHP resources.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is just a free freelance job that I'm doing (for a family friend). I'm not even sure if they're going to pay for the hosting of the website at this point. I would love to use Sendgrid or AWS' SES but I'm not sure that they'll go for it!